# Can you use an abstract class to construct a generic?

Tags: generics, dart, constructor

Im trying to use a constructor on a generic but since a generic ( represented here with T ) can be anything I'm trying to make T be of type "RedClass". If I then pass a class to represent T that also extends "RedClass" I would be able to use a RedClass constructor on T, right?

```
abstract class RedClass {
  RedClass();

  RedClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
}

class BlueClass extends RedClass {
  BlueClass();
}

class FinalClass<T extends RedClass> {

// Inside FinalClass I can create a BlueClass from the generic T

final happyBlueClass = T.fromJson(someJson)

}

// When creating the FinalClass i pass a class that also extends RedClass
return FinalClass<BlueClass>()
```

But trying this the generic T does not seem to get access to any .fromJson() constructor.
Any ideas?

Comment: Inside `FinalClass` `T` is not an object you can do things on, it's a type. If you want to call instance methods on instances of `RedClass` you have to create an instance of `RedClass` and pass it into the method that wants to call `fromJson`

Comment: This is true @Smutje, but in this case I'm looking for a way to create an instance of BlueClass inside the FinalClass without the FinalClass knowing anything about a BlueClass.

Comment: Either `FinalClass` will need to take an already-constructed instance of `T`, or it will need to take a callback that constructs and returns a `T`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the suggestions. I really appreciate it.

My solution for now to make the T of FinalClass as generic as possible I needed to pass the constuctors to FinalClass using a provider earlier in the widget tree.

```
class FinalClassDataBuilder {
 final Type model;
 final Function builder;

 FinalClassDataBuilder({this.model, this.builder});
}

class FinalClassProvider extends StatelessWidget {
 final Widget child;
 final List<FinalClassDataBuilder> modelbuilderList;

 const FinalClassProvider({Key key, this.child, this.modelbuilderList})
  : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider<List<FinalClassDataBuilder>>(
   create: (_) => [...modelbuilderList],
   child: child,
  );
 }
}

class FinalClass<T> {
 ...
 final List<FinalClassDataBuilder> builders =
    Provider.of<List<FinalClassDataBuilder>>(context);

final List<<FinalClassDataBuilder>> result = builders
    .where((datamodel) => datamodel.model.toString() == T.toString())
    .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are trying to do directly.

You cannot call static methods on type variables, only on the class/mixin/extension they are actually declared in. Static methods need to be known *statically*, at compile-time, in order to be called.

If you want to create an instance of the type variable, you need to pass a way to do so to the class. Maybe:

```dart
class FinalClass<T extends RedClass> {
  final T Function(dynamic) _fromJson;

  FinalClass(T Function(dynamic) fromJson) : _fromJson = fromJson;
  void someMethod(someJson) {
    ... 
    var happyBlueClass = _fromJson(someJson);
    ...
  }
}
```